Add-AppxProvisionedPackage failing for eappx
I'm trying to sideload an encrypted appx (eappx) app via powershell.
Add-AppxPackage -Path ./Appfile.eappx works fine.
However it only installs the app for the current user.
To install for all users on the machine I've seen suggestions to use Add-AppxProvisionedPackage.
This works installing and appx but fails installing the eappx with the error below:
Works:
Add-AppxProvisionedPackage -Online -PackagePath ./Appfile.appx -SkipLicense
Fails: Add-AppxProvisionedPackage -Online -PackagePath ./Appfile.eappx -SkipLicense
Add-AppxProvisionedPackage : Add-AppxProvisionedPackage failed. Error code = 0x8051100f
At line:1 char:1
+ Add-AppxProvisionedPackage -Online -PackagePath ./Appfile.eappx  ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Add-AppxProvisionedPackage], COMException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Dism.Commands.AddAppxProvisionedPackageCommand

Error 0x8051100F is "OPC_E_ZIP_MISSING_END_OF_CENTRAL_DIRECTORY"
Do you know if it's possible to install eappx files via Add-AppxProvisionedPackage?
Thanks

AFAIK an encrypted appx package is not provisionable. You can only install the appx package as a provisioned one. Maybe @Hans Passant has more knowledge on that
